# In Java - Can I set log level pr thread?

Tags: java, logging, java.util.logging

I always wondered if it would be possible to programatically set the log level of java.util.logging on a pr thread level.

The usecase is, in a web server. If my code detects that a certain user has an abnormal level of errors, I would like to enable trace logging for that customer.

I was thinking of doing this with a servletfilter, and tie it to his session id. But as far as I can see, the log levels I can set on appenders are not thread affine. I.e. if I set the root level to FINE, it will affect all threads in the system, and the log fills up with the other 200 simultanious users traffic. Sure, I can then filter the log afterwards, but the performance hit will occur anyway.

Does anyone have experience with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I always wondered if it would be possible to programatically set the log level of java.util.logging on a pr thread level.

Create a [log filter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/Filter.html) to capture the user context and set the level to ALL for the filtered object:

```
   public class UserFilter implements Filter {

    private final Level lvl;
    private final Object userContext;

    public UserFilter(Level originalLevel, Object userContext) {
        this.lvl = originalLevel;
        this.userContext = userContext;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isLoggable(LogRecord record) {
        if (!belongsTo(record, userContext)) {
            int levelValue = this.lvl.intValue();
            if (record.getLevel().intValue() < levelValue
                    || levelValue == Level.OFF.intValue()) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }


    private boolean belongsTo(LogRecord record) {
        /**
         * Insert logic here.
         */
        //return ((Integer) this.userContext) == record.getThreadId();
        return true;
    }
}
```

For your use case you should be able to create a servlet filter which will:

1. Create a log filter which will identify a user and capture the current log level.
2. Install the log filter then change the level to FINE.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you should always be able to call `log(level, message);` directly and get the actual level by using some thread local mapping.

You could also write some wrapper which handles this for you, i.e. with something like this:

```
public void debugExceptCritical(Logger l, String message) {
  //critical would be your per-thread flag, 
  //just make sure to reset it when it is no longer used, e.g. in a servlet filter
  l.log( critical  ? ERROR : DEBUG, message ); 
}
```

Alternatively you could try and get the class where this is called (I did it somewhere but don't remember the details, so I'd have to look it up) and use this info to get the logger inside the method.

Looking up the caller:

```
StackTraceElement[] stackTrace = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();
for( StackTraceElement elem : stackTrace ) {
  //look for the debugExceptCritical method or maybe just the class it contains
  //if found take the class name of the next element to look up the correct logger  
}
```

An alternative to this, depending on which logging framework you actually use, might be to hook some per-thread filter/appender/whatever into it. In Log4J I'd either try to add my own appender which then checks the `critical` flag and changes the log event's level or always log critical actions and use a per-thread filter which rejects those log events when the `critial` flag is not set.